# is there any method to automatically incrementing the value of padding

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
if(val[2]==="Dir"){
var newPath = val[6]+"\\"+val[0];
console.log(newPath);
stringDir += '<p class="dirClass"  current_directory="'+newPath+'" >'  + val[0]+'</p>';}
$(this).after(stringDir);
```

Because I have a p tag and I used after() to  p.The problem is by the use of this each p is coming after its parent p so that I cant give any padding to its child.I really want parent child alignment, that is some left padding to each child.

Comment: you should format your code; it's unreadable in its current state

Comment: @Andrew Ok , I just updated.